# Wordpress loop put title into variable

Tags: loop, permalinks, variables, get-the-title

I am trying to get the permalink and title into variables to use outside of a loop - I have made it work for the thumbnail but for some reason can t get it to work for these two.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="medium-12 medium-centered columns">

                <?php global $post; // required
                $args = array('category' => 5,
                             'posts_per_page'=> 7); // include category 5 (Action)
                $custom_posts = get_posts($args); 
               $count3=1;                  


                foreach($custom_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); 
               $v =  get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'medium');
               $var = "img".$count3;
                $$var = $v;

                $l =  get_the_permalink();
               $link = "link".$count3;
                $$l = $l;

                $t = get_the_title();
                 $tt =  "title".$count3;
                $$t = $t;


               ?>


               <?php $count3++; ?>

               <?php   endforeach; ?>

                <div class="row collapse imageGrid photogrid" data-equalizer="fullRow">

                        <div class="medium-4 columns" data-equalizer-watch="fullRow">
                              <a href="<?php echo $link1; ?>">
                                <span class="centertitle"><?php echo $title1; ?></span>  
                            <?php echo $img1; ?>
                                   </a>
                       </div>


                       <div class="medium-4 columns" data-equalizer-watch="fullRow"  data-equalizer="watchColumn">
                           <div class="row collapse"  data-equalizer-watch="watchColumn">
                            <?php echo $img2; ?>
                           </div>
                            <div class="row collapse" >
                                <div class="medium-6 columns" data-equalizer-watch="watchColumn"> <?php echo $img3; ?></div>
                                <div class="medium-6 columns" data-equalizer-watch="watchColumn"><?php echo $img4; ?></div>
                           </div>
                       </div>

                        <div class="medium-4 columns" data-equalizer-watch="fullRow"  data-equalizer="watchColumn2">

                            <div class="row collapse">
                                <div class="medium-6 columns" ><?php echo $img5; ?></div>
                                <div class="medium-6 columns" ><?php echo $img6; ?></div>
                           </div>
                             <div class="row collapse" data-equalizer-watch="watchColumn2">
                            <?php echo $img7; ?>
                           </div>
                       </div>

                        <?php   wp_reset_query(); ?>   

             </div> 
         </div>
```

I have tried different ways of putting the title including:

$t = the_title('', '', false);

as 
 $t = the_title() echos the title straight away.

Any help in how to put them into the variable would be much appreciated

Comment: can i ask what the down vote was for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating variables on the fly like that is not needed. Just use an array instead.

```
$myvars = [];
```

inside your foreach loop you can:

```
$myvars[] = array('title'=>$t,'image'=>$v);
```

After your loop you can:

```
//First title, First image
echo $myvars[0]['title'];
echo $myvars[0]['image'];

//Second title, Second image
echo $myvars[1]['title'];
echo $myvars[1]['image'];
```

This way you can always print_r($myvars) and see the content inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Please Use This

```
$t = get_the_title('');
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either - the following is empty  - <?php echo $title1; ?>

Comment: you want to title add in a variable and that variable want to check title was empty or not?

Comment: no i need the title to be put in a variable with the count3 so that i can then retrieve the variable outside of the loop (if you see what i have done with the thumbnail this works ok)